# Open specific Excel file in new instance of Excel when file is opened

Tags: excel, vba

**Info:**

I have an Excel file named Demo.xlsm

This file contains a userform named UserForm1 which automatically loads when the file is opened.

The workbook named Demo.xlsm is also visible in the background behind the userform when the file is opened.

**Problem:**

I often have an Excel application already open on my desktop with various workbooks and worksheets containing information I use on a daily basis. As it stands, if I go to open the Demo.xlsm file, it will open in the current Excel application along with all of the other workbook/worksheets I am using.

First: I would like for the Demo.xlsm file to automatically open in an entirely separate instance/Excel application than my other works.

Second: I would like for only the userform to be visible. (I have no need/use for the workbook/worksheets to be visible in the background.)

Third: If its possible to have the 2nd instance of the Excel application to be minimized while still displaying the userform, that would be perfect. (Currently, if I attempt to minimize the 2nd instance of the Excel application, the userform is also minimized)

```
  Private Sub Workbook_Open()
  Dim objExcel
  Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
  objExcel.Visible = True

  UserForm1.Show

  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  Set newBook = Workbooks.Open(Demo.xlsm)
  Windows(Demo.xlsm).Visible = False
  Application.ScreenUpdating = True 

  End Sub
```

I feel that I am not going about this the right way...

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I don't know your broader purpose - but most of what you describe, only the form is visible - sounds like an addin.

Comment: pnuts - I appreciate the link...checked it out, but I don't necessarily want every excel file to open in a new instance, just this specific file.

Comment: Doug Glancy - Unfortunately, I have no experience with any addins or how to utilize them. The main purpose of my request is to essentially have the userform act as if its a standalone program and not appear to the enduser that the userform is necessarily part of excel. The userform should act as a program which automatically loads when the execl file is opened. The form accepts user input and generates an email in outlook and sends it with all appropriate formatting.

Answer (score 3):

This is what I do, and it works lovely. I have a sheet with a nice big picture, and the picture has a macro, which is:

```
Dim appXL As New Excel.Application

appXL.Workbooks.Open "G:\All Users\Jurie\Test\Hotel Maintenance V1SE.xlsm"
appXL.ActiveWorkbook.Windows(1).Visible = True
appXL.Visible = True
Workbooks("Hotel Stay Easy Maintenance Program.xlsm").Close   SaveChanges:=True
ThisWorkbook.Activate
```

This opens my file in its own instance and I can close it as I want, it does not interfere with any other open files.

Comment: This answer isn't straightforward to the OP's requirement. The OP wants the new instance of Excel to be minimized while the form that loads from the workbook that is opened in here still remains on top and is shown to the user.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me.  Copy paste this code into the ThisWorkbook object:

```
Option Explicit

Dim objExcel As Excel.Application

Dim FileName As String

Public Sub workbook_open()
    FileName = ThisWorkbook.FullName
    If vbReadOnly <> 0 Then
        Exit Sub
    Else
        objExcel.Workbooks.Open FileName:=FileName
        ThisWorkbook.Saved = True
        ThisWorkbook.Close
        objExcel.Quit
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

For your `Workbook_Open`, do something like below should get you close.

```
If Application.Workbooks.Count > 1 Then
    Call Shell(Application.Path & Application.PathSeparator & "excel.exe " & ThisWorkbook.FullName)
    ThisWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=False
Else
    UserForm1.Show
End If
```

I tested this and there is another "Excel.exe" in Task Manager, so it should be right.

Comment: Hmm...not sure if this is what I'm looking for. I tested it and it doesn't seem to behave like what I'm looking for...I'll play around with it some more and see if I can figure it out

Answer (score 0):

Copy a shortcut to Excel and then right-click, select properties and add to the end of the target " - "C:\Demo.xlsm"" (exclude the first and last quotation marks and replace with the real filepath for your file.