# Copying and renaming a file error "Out of Memory"

Tags: excel, vba, copy, out-of-memory

I have an Excel file with a form. When the form is filled correctly an OK button can be pressed.
The button function is to create a file name, copy paste a master file and a specific folder (the address is stored in a cell) and rename this file.
Afterwards the file is opened, some cells are filled with values and is saved and closed.

```vb
Private Sub S_START_BTN_Click()
    
    Dim Box_No As Integer                           'Box Number of the Session
    Dim D As String, M As String, YE As String      'Date Elements
    Dim O_LINK As String                            'Directory of Master File
    Dim Line As String                              'Production Line
    Dim COSE As String                              'Shop Order Text
    Dim P_Coord As String                           'Row at which is the right project
    Dim P_QT As Integer                             'target quanityt for the box
    Dim CODEX As String                             'Flag for session
    Dim CODEXO As String                            'Flag for session Open
    Dim S_Coord As String                           'Row at which is the active session is
    Dim SN_Open As String                           'Box tag of the open session
    Dim S_LINK As String                            'Directory of the new file
    Dim nomefile As String, nomemaster As String
    
    
    'Get Data from the File
    
    Box_No = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("SESSIONS_LOG").Range("H2").Value + 1
    O_LINK = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("SESSIONS_LOG").Range("G2").Value & "\" & "VERIFICATOR_MASTER.xlsm"
    Line = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("SESSIONS_LOG").Range("D3").Value
    
    'Get Date Elements
    
    D = Format$(Day(Date), "0#")
    M = Format$(Month(Date), "0#")
    YE = Year(Date)
    
    'Get Shop Order
    
    If S_SOYN_DT.Value = True Then
        COSE = "NO_SHOP_ORDER"
    Else
        COSE = S_SO_DT
    End If
    
    'Get the target quantity
    
    P_Coord = "K" & ThisWorkbook.Sheets("PROJECTS_DATABASE").Range("C:C").Find(What:=S_PS_DT, LookIn:=xlValues).Row
    P_QT = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("PROJECTS_DATABASE").Range(P_Coord).Value
    
    'Make the flag and check if other boxes like this exist
    
    CODEX = YE & M & D & "-" & Line & "-" & S_PS_DT & "-" & COSE & "-" & P_QT & "-" & Left(S_PT_DT, 1)
    CODEXO = CODEX & "-" & "O"
    
    If Not IsError(Application.Match(CODEXO, ThisWorkbook.Sheets("SESSIONS_LOG").Range("J:J"), 0)) Then
      
        If MsgBox("Another session with same parameters is active, open it?", vbQuestion + vbYesNo, "Ready to Exit?") = vbNo Then
         
            'There is an open session, I don't want to open it
         
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets("SESSIONS_LOG").Range("A6:M6").Delete Shift:=xlUp
            Unload Me
            
        Else
            
            'There is an open session, I want to open it
            
            S_Coord = "F" & ThisWorkbook.Sheets("SESSIONS_LOG").Range("J:J").Find(What:=CODEXO, LookIn:=xlValues).Row
            SN_Open = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("SESSIONS_LOG").Range(S_Coord).Value
            S_LINK = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("SESSIONS_LOG").Range("G1").Value & "\" & SN_Open & ".xlsm"
            Workbooks.Open (S_LINK)
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets("SESSIONS_LOG").Range("A6:M6").Delete Shift:=xlUp
            Unload Me
        
         End If
    
    Else
    
    'There is no other sessions with this tag, make a new
    
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("SESSIONS_LOG").Range("J6").Value = CODEXO
        SN_Open = CODEX & "-" & Worksheets("SESSIONS_LOG").Range("A6").Value
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("SESSIONS_LOG").Range("F6").Value = SN_Open
        S_LINK = Worksheets("SESSIONS_LOG").Range("G1").Value & "\" & SN_Open & ".xlsm"
        
        'Make new file
        
        FileCopy O_LINK, S_LINK
        Workbooks.Open (S_LINK)
        
        nomefile = SN_Open & ".xlsm"
        nomemaster = ThisWorkbook.Name
        
        'Write variables
        
        With Workbooks(nomefile).Sheets("VERIFICATION_MASTER_FULL")
            .Range("A2").Formula = Workbooks(nomemaster).Sheets("SESSIONS_LOG").Range("F4").Value                   'Supplier address
            .Range("J2").Formula = Date
            .Range("E8").Formula = Workbooks(nomemaster).Sheets("SESSIONS_LOG").Range("A6").Value                   'Box Number
            .Range("C8").Formula = Workbooks(nomemaster).Sheets("SESSIONS_LOG").Range("D3").Value                   'Line
            .Range("C10").Formula = Workbooks(nomemaster).Sheets("SESSIONS_LOG").Range("C4").Value                  'operator ID
            .Range("F8").Formula = COSE                                                                             'SO
            .Range("B12").Formula = Workbooks(nomemaster).Sheets("SESSIONS_LOG").Range("C4").Value                  'operator ID
            .Range("C12").Formula = Workbooks(nomemaster).Sheets("SESSIONS_LOG").Range("C3").Value                  'operator level
        End With
        
        'Close, save and unload
        
        Workbooks(nomefile).Close SaveChanges:=True
        Worksheets("SESSIONS_LOG").Range("H2").Value = Worksheets("SESSIONS_LOG").Range("H2").Value + 1
        Unload Me
       
    End If
    
End Sub
```

After random times, from 1 to 40, Excel gives me an error "Out of Memory". After which I lose the links in my files (which are transferred to the roaming file) and the program crashes. The file has no values, only few cells filled with numbers, no formulas and no conditional formatting of any kind. Same for the copied file, also no values, not formulas and no formatting.

I tried possible Microsoft workarounds but many of them are not applicable because I do not have formulas. PC is recent, 16GB ram, office is updated.

Comment: Instead of testing the length of your day value and `D = "0" & Day(Date)` just format it `D = Format$(Day(Date), "0#")` much easier.

Comment: use `Option Explicit` and explicitly declare your variable types. Also set variables to common objects and use `With` blocks.

Comment: I think the issue is mainly caused by a spaghetti code that is hard to read and does to many things at once. Use sub procedures and functions, make sure **every** `Range` object has a workbook **and** worksheet referenced. Instead of repeating references like `Workbooks(nomefile).Sheets("VERIFICATION_MASTER_FULL")` all the time use `With` statements or set variables that you can re-use. Tidy up your code so you have at least a chance to see what is going wrong.

Comment: Dear @Scott, so You mean use `Option Explicit` to declare all variables before for example `Dim COSE As String` and so on, right? And for `with` blocks what do You mean exactly?  Why this is the solution to my problem (what is the route cause)?

Comment: Dear @Pᴇʜ, ok, I will do it, but I have same exact other files, doing it and this issue never came up. Why in this particular file is happening?

Comment: This is not directly te issue, but you would do that at first to be able to read your code properly and therefore be able to find an issue at all. If the code is a long spaghetti it is hard to read therefore hard to find an issue. Google how to use the `With` statement. It is a method to stop repeating the same code over and over.

Comment: Here again a new code, I did both task, `Option Explicit` and `With`. The code is simple, is pointless to divide it into different routines, I also placed all comments, still out of memory at second run.

Comment: How big are your files? Which version of Excel are you using 32 bit or 64 bit (If you are not sure check [this](https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/vba-to-determine-if-user-is-running-64bit-excel-or-32bit-excel.579410/))? Note that 32 bit Excel has a 2 GB memory limit. If you open/close files sometimes the memory does not get cleared properly. So this might cause the issue on **second run**. Close and re-open Excel completely (check task manager) between the first and second run to verify if this is the issue.

Comment: As soon as you have any problem with a VBA file, do as I and others always suggest: Use Option Explicit. It's a valuable tool to find variables that are not defined. Is there ANY reason why you resist using this statement?

Comment: Change your `Integer` declarations to `Long`. Long variables handle much bigger numbers than Integer. You wouldn't think it would matter, but it's often a source of `Out of Memory` issues in Excel.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ, file is 1MB and master to copy is 23 KB, so size is limited. Is strange to me why this happens on this file and not on others, on the same directory doing the same job without all Your valuable suggested improvements, which are clear to me. What si special/wrong about it!? Can it be something at system level? Sure @Scott, I will change to `Long` all integer. @StureS, just because I'm not trained or expert and never made the difference, now code in the post is changed.

Comment: Can I share the complete file with You?

Comment: I also noticed, it happens after I leave Excel open long item without using it. I think is no code related but something else should be happening.

Comment: Note that the 2 GB memory limit is not corresponding *directly* to the file size. File size can be an indicator (if you have big files it is more likely) but still small files can produce huge memory load. As I said every file that was opened and closed within an Excel instance can leave some garbage in memory. Also this limit is not per file but per Excel instance. So the easiest way not to run into this issue is using a fresh instance (close/re-open Excel).

Comment: Also have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18775969/open-specific-excel-file-in-new-instance-of-excel-when-file-is-opened) how to open a new Excel instance (and a workbook in this instance) with VBA. If the instance is closed and a new one is opened for the second run it is less likely to run into memory issues. Be aware that opening a new instance will be slightly slower than using the existing one. Give it a try.

Comment: Hi all, I have tried to make a simplified file, 42KB with only the Macro doing the job of coping. I started from scratch, used `Long`, I placed the file in a new directory on desktop. I closed all apps, only excel on. I got Out of Memory error after 20 times I use the macro. On the same directory I have 300 MB files doing same and never had issues with memory. Any other idea?

Comment: My colleagues trying the same file on their PC do not get the error. :(

Comment: The file to be copied have for first time CODE 39 font to use bar codes, is the only real difference. Can this be an issue?

Comment: *"after 20 times I use the macro"* 20 times without closing Excel completely in between?

Comment: Yes, but this file has to work in a production environment, close the file is no option.

Comment: Open and closing many files in a row had always caused issues for me at some point. Try to open each file in a new instance like in the [link I gave above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18775969/open-specific-excel-file-in-new-instance-of-excel-when-file-is-opened)

Comment: Thanks, I will try. However the point remains, we have files in production floor PCs which creates hundreds of files a day of 3/400 MB each in series, no issue, same "Spaghetti code" :)

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you handle empty content that takes up memory.

Try to substitute in the code everything related to whole columns (which affect all the rows of the file, whether they are full or empty)

Range("C:C")

For a more specific range that takes up less memory

Range("C1:C10000")

Bye

Comment: I've done it, same issue. Here link, You can try the file. [https://drive.google.com/file/d/16DIou_K0G_jGuFUKTRPDBIgTvB_6Ynak/view?usp=sharing]

Comment: No issues on my PC. Have you test de macro in other PC?

Comment: Ok, yes we do not have issues in other PCs for now. If we take out the Code39 part, then I also do not have issues. So the bar code is creating somehow the problem. Now we downloaded a Microsoft bar code creator for excel, let's see if this delivers better results and I keep getting it.

Answer (score 0):

After doing some tests, the problem is not in the VBA code (even if is a Spaghetti Code) but the issue is in the use of CODE 39 as font to create bar codes. If the font is used the large amount of files cannot be made because it uses somehow memory.

We solved it by instead of using the font, we use a macro VBA to do a API to google ot get back the picture with the code, we resize and paste it in the right place in the sticker.