# How can I open one specific spreadsheet in its own instance of VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to force one specific spreadsheet to open in its own instance of Excel. It contains a lot of macros and userforms and behaves almost like its own application, and I want to isolate it from any other instance of Excel and any workbooks that a user opening this spreadsheet might already have open. Any help would be appreciated.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the answers from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18775969)?

If you want to open the workbook from VBA then [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33394022) should work for you.

If you want to open it from a shortcut in a new instance then [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36159045) is your solution.

I can confirm that both methods work in Excel 2010, if you wanted something else please specify your question more.

Comment: Hi Cook IT, thanks for responding, I have tried the three solutions in the answers; the first one freezes Excel and gives a warning that "Excel is waiting for another application to complete an OLE action" . The third method with the shell call ignores spaces in the filepath so I changed the filepath to have an underscore and it treats those as spaces? The other method mentions vbReadOnly which is irrelevant but when I change the condition to workbooks.count it throws a runtime error 91.

Comment: Ok that's really strange, sadly without knowing your setup better I won't be able to help.  Firstly from your comment I assume that you want to open the workbook from another workbook via VBA, is that correct? If so then you may have something in that first workbook that messes with opening it in a new instance. Try opening your "hyper-spreadsheet" from a new, completely empty workbook with just a module with the code from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33394022) (without the .Close part of course) in a Sub and see if that works.